How start python-telegram-bot in a Thread
I need to run the telegram bot in a separete thread to have the main thread free, but I have bad times tring this.
Follow the piece of code that I have used to test
bot_thread.py

    import logging
    import asyncio
    from telegram import Update
    from telegram.ext import Application, ContextTypes, CommandHandler
    from threading import Thread
    from multiprocessing import Process
    
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO
    )
    
    
    class Bot(Thread):
        async def start_msg(self, update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
            await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="I'm a bot, please talk to me!")
    
        def run(self):
            async def hello(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
                await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Starting bot")
    
            key = open('../data/keys', 'r').read()
            application = Application.builder().token(key).build()
    
            job_queue = application.job_queue
            job_queue.run_once(hello, 90)
    
            start_handler = CommandHandler('start', self.start_msg)
            application.add_handler(start_handler)
    
            application.run_polling()


bot.py
from bot_thread import Bot

Bot().start()

When tries to start the bot it gives a error
(RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.):
> python .\bot_wrapper.py
2024-05-09 15:04:13,916 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "bot_thread.py", line 32, in run
    application.run_polling()
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telegram\ext\_application.py", line 838, in run_polling
    return self.__run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telegram\ext\_application.py", line 1020, in __run
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 677, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py:1047: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Updater.start_polling' was never awaited
  self._invoke_excepthook(self)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

